# Pull an object using blender

Tags: rigid-body-simulation, cloth-simulation, rigidbody

I am trying to simulate pulling using blender. In this picture, two cubes are connected using a cable. When I move one cube in the pull direction, I want the other cube to be pulled in that direction. The cable is rigid and it should remain unstretched. I am familiar with the cloth modifier which I use for modelling the cable. But, when I use it I am able to move only one body and the cable is getting stretched.
Please help !

[image]

Comment: what does it give if you parent the other cube to the vertices that are at the tip of the rope?

Comment: When I do that, the cubes and the rope move around as a single object, it doesn't look like an actual 'pulling'

Answer (score 0):

In order to get a rope-like effect with cloth simulations, it's best to use a long plane, like you see here:

[image]

(Normally you wouldn't need an edge loop in the middle, but in this case it's necessary because there'll be a vertex parent later.)

Assign a weight paint to one end of the rope and then set that weight paint to the "pin group" in your cloth settings:

[image]

If you now place a cube on that side of the plane, parent the plane to the cube, play the animation and move the cube around, you can see that it works, but there's not a cube on the other side yet.

So place a cube on the other side and select the plane while holding down `shift`, so that you have both of them selected. (Make sure the plane is the one that's highlighted.) Then go into edit mode. Selected the three vertices you see in the image below and then go to `Vertex > Make Vertex Parent`

[image]

Now if you press play and move the cube around (Note: It only works if you move the cube which you parented the plane to.), it should work and the result should look something like you see in the image below:

[image]

Hope that this was helpful. If you want the rope to be something other than a plane, that you should look up a tutorial on how to use the "Surface Deform" modifier.

Comment: Thank you so much. It is working like a charm. cheers :)